# Bookmarklets for quick sharing in Google+

Tags: google-plus, bookmarklet

Google Reader supports [bookmarklets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklets)  that allow for the quick sharing of anything that can be displayed on a browser. I believe the code for the Google Reader bookmarket is this (from the Google Reader interface):

```
javascript:var%20b=document.body;var%20GR________bookmarklet_domain='http://www.google.com';if(b&&!document.xmlVersion){void(z=document.createElement('script'));void(z.src='http://www.google.com/reader/ui/link-bookmarklet.js');void(b.appendChild(z));}else{}
```

One of the advantages of using bookmarklets is that they can be associated with quick search links, and can be triggered with short text strings typed in the URL field of a browser (both Chrome and Firefox support this). Is there any bookmarklet known for sharing in Google+?

Comment: There are several "+1" bookmarklets out there, but so far "plus-one-ing" something just adds it to the "+1" section of your Google profile. I've come up empty so far for bookmarklets to make it easy to share in Google+. I do, however, use [the Chrome extension Whitingx suggests](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/17113/bookmarklets-for-quick-sharing-in-google/17122#17122).

Comment: I can't answer yet, so just commenting... I did find a bookmarklet that worked nicely. Found it here: http://www.labnol.org/internet/google-plus-one-bookmarklet/19474/. The nice part is that the same bookmarklet first +1's the site and then allows you to share it.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure of a bookmarklet but have you seen Surplus;

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pfphgaimeghgekhncbkfblhdhfaiaipf

a Chrome extension for Google+

> Post or respond from within the popup

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I'm well late arriving here, but I thought I'd add anyway.

[My bookmarklets](https://code.google.com/archive/p/google-plus-1-bookmarklet/) with +1 and share functionality.