# Google Plus `Stream This` bookmarklet

Tags: bookmarklet, google-plus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bookmarklets for quick sharing in Google+](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/17113/bookmarklets-for-quick-sharing-in-google)

I'm looking for bookmarklet allowing me to quickly add a new post in a selected `stream` to my Google+ home.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for here. "Streams" are what the people in your Circles are posting, with the main Stream being all of them aggregated. "Sparks" are terms you want to see news items for. What is it you want this bookmarklet to do for you?

Comment: Sorry I didn't make myself clear enough :) I've updated it. I need to `post a new entry` on a certain `stream`.

Comment: None that I've found. I have found a [bookmarklet to "+1"](http://www.labnol.org/internet/google-plus-one-bookmarklet/19474/) something, and I very much like the [Surplus Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pfphgaimeghgekhncbkfblhdhfaiaipf?hl=en-US) which, among other things, does what you want. But it's not a bookmarklet.

Answer (score 0):

The streams correspond to the circles you have defined. If you want to add streams, you must add circles -- and this is something that a bookmarklet cannot do (to the best of my knowledge). Even if a bookmarklet *could* create a circle for you, that circle would not contain any people, so the stream would be empty.

Comment: Well, maybe the bookmarklet can create a popup windows and let us choose the circles from there. In case you didn't know about bit.ly bookmarklet, it is quite cool when clicked and showing a form allowing me to interact with it as a windows